# How to increase default xterm buffer size

Tags: xterm

I understand to create a new xterm with 1000 buffer size I can do xterm -sl 1000 &. How would I do this by default for all xterms? If this cannot be done, how do I do it for the current xterm? It looks like I need to use XTerm*saveLines: 1000 in a file, but which file do I use and do I need to do anything after writing that file?

**edit:**
I have tried `XTerm*saveLines: 5000` in .Xresources and .Xdefaults (and at the same time in both files), but no change in behaviour. Do I need to resource or restart anything? I am running on a VNC if that changes anything.

Answer (score 2):

### Defaults

Edit you're `~/.Xresources` File

Arch has some pretty good documentation on [Xterm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xterm) and [X resources](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources#Getting_Started)

<strike>`Xterm*vt100*geometry: 80x50`</strike> 

Edit: whoops you didn't ask for size

Comment: update question with your suggestion

Comment: Just for some context, what is your Desktop environment / Window Manager?

The Arch Wiki mentions making a change in an xterm, i.e. typing the `XTerm*saveLines: 5000` and then merging your resources like so:
`xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`

Comment: I'm not actually sure. I use VNC to access a server, which I think is CentOS/GNOME. `XTerm*saveLines: 5000` returns `XTerm*saveLines:: Too many arguments.`

Comment: Hrmm this is probably why you didn't see a change when adding to `.Xdefaults`I'd say read through the XTerm manpage and once you figure out the proper syntax of the size command and can get it to be accepted in a live terminal, just add that to your `.Xdefaults`

Comment: Makes sense. I made my `.Xdefaults` file myself. Are there any other necessary lines in there, or can it be blank except for the line I am trying to add?