# Change xterm buffer size to unlimited for session

Tags: xterm, openbsd

This question is similar to [How to increase default xterm buffer size](https://superuser.com/q/640636/173513). I'd like to change my xterm buffer size (the buffer being how much I can scroll back) to unlimited on OpenBSD 5.7.

The other questions (and similar questions) state to use `-sl XXX`, where `XXX` is a size like 1000. But I want unlimited, and not a fixed size. I also want to ensure the history is only available for the session, and its not persisted like a command history. Finally, this is OpenBSD, and I dont have `~/.Xresources`.

Answer (score 3):

xterm's scrollback is limited because it allocates an array *once*(actually a FIFO) to keep track of the scrolled lines.  Doing this *once* is much faster than periodically reallocating.

You could set the scrollback limit to a very large number (even a million), which is probably long enough for practical purposes.  There is no such thing as "unlimited" when the data is stored in memory, in any case.

Before a [rewrite in 2009](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_244), the practical limit for scrollback was on the order of 10,000 lines due to the way it updated the buffer.  Now, it is essentially dependent upon how much memory you choose to use (with the caveat that resizing a window with a million lines of scrollback may be slow).